# How to store the random key and iv created when trying to encrypt in ruby?

Tags: ruby, encryption, openssl

I'm currently working on a project where  I will be storing data of users in text files.  I would like to encrypt these files using the OpenSSL library within Ruby.  I am able to encrypt files using randomly created key and iv values.  As the program won't be running on a server but locally I would like to export these values with a password so that a different method could decrypt the information.

```
require "openssl"

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
cipher.encrypt

key = cipher.random_key

iv = cipher.random_iv
encrypted = cipher.update("test.txt") + cipher.final
File.open("temp.txt", "w+") do |file|
    file.write(encrypted)
end
```

If I don't use a random key it won't encrypt the information or returns errors.

```
'update': key not set (OpenSSL::Cipther::CipherError)
```

When I try to use the export commands (with random key) I also get an error saying that it isn't a method.

```
'export' for #<string:0x00000000065659b8> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: A suggestion since you're new: please take a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will make it much easier to answer your questions if you follow that guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not experienced with developing encryption schemes, so I'm going to suggest you not implement this yourself. The built-in OpenSSL library does not protect you from making security mistakes. As you've noticed, it provides no guidance on how to securely handle the key and iv (and doing it wrong would be insecure).

I recommend using the `rbnacl` gem, which has:

> The `RbNaCl::SimpleBox` class provides a simple, easy-to-use cryptographic API where all of the hard decisions have been made for you in advance. If you're looking to encrypt something, and you don't know much about cryptography, this is probably what you want to be using.

Here's a full end-to-end example with outputting to & loading from disk:

```rb
require 'rbnacl'

generated_key = RbNaCl::Random.random_bytes(RbNaCl::SecretBox.key_bytes)
box = RbNaCl::SimpleBox.from_secret_key(generated_key)

ciphertext = box.encrypt('plaintext')

# save both artifacts to disk
File.open('cipher.bin', 'w') { |f| f.write(ciphertext) }
File.open('key.bin', 'w') { |f| f.write(generated_key) }

# decrypt by reading artifacts from disk
# this could be done in separate program
ciphertext_from_file = File.read('cipher.bin', mode: 'rb') # r -> "read", b -> "binary"
key_from_file = File.read('key.bin', mode: 'rb')
regenerated_box = RbNaCl::SimpleBox.from_secret_key(key_from_file)

regenerated_box.decrypt(ciphertext_from_file)
# => 'plaintext'

# cleanup
File.delete('cipher.bin') if File.exist?('cipher.bin')
File.delete('key.bin') if File.exist?('key.bin')
```

Note that `generated_key` and `ciphertext` are both binary strings. If you don't want to save raw binary files, then convert them using something like `Base64.encode64` or `Digest.hexencode`, converting them to printable characters. That way, they'll be printable, copy/paste-able, and you won't need to do a "read binary" with `'rb'`.

Comment: I was able to get encryption done with this gem but I run into the same problem.  For this gem, it does generate a random key but I don't see in the documentation how to securely pass this anywhere.  All of the examples are in the same block of code meaning the key value can be kept.  I have my first ruby file encrypt the message and then want a second ruby file to decrypt it.  I tried to cross OpenSSL exporting methods and the gem.  No avail.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the problem is? Sounds like you've managed to encrypt/decrypt just fine. Are you asking what to do with the key, and how to pass it to the decryptor? Using a locked door analogy: sounds like you've installed a lock and have been able to lock/unlock the door just fine. Are you asking how to securely hand someone the key for the door?

Comment: Following the analogy, I am a locksmith.  And I have created a lock and put it on someone's door.  I want to find a way to hand this key over to the owner.  The door is locked but the owner of the house can't get in because the locksmith is keeping the key then destroying it.  So I 'm trying to in essence password protect the key file so that the owner can gain access to the key.  However, I am doing this in two separate functions which means the first program closes and the key is effectively lost.

Comment: Clearly, you can't destroy the key, you have to deliver it for decryption. What troubles are you having in simply "handing the user the key"? It sounds like you have some operational problem (not an encryption one) but haven't explained anything relevant to that problem yet.

Comment: Basically, after encrypting I don't know how to recover the key.  I have two files.  I have encryptor and decryptor so I can learn the basics of the gem.  After running the encryption I am able to create a file that isn't readable and needs the key to be understood.  I haven't found a way to use this gem to export the key, password protects it, and then load it later for the decryptor file.  In the documentation for the gem, it only shows the examples in the same project file.  I am having trouble doing this in separate files.  I can do it within the same file fine.

Comment: Encryption, in general, involves taking a payload and generating TWO artifacts: a ciphertext and a key. You need to deliver BOTH artifacts to the user -- the only difference between them is that only the key needs to be delivered securely. As an example, if you save the ciphertext as a file, that file can be sent in the open. You can also save the key as a file, but you need to send that file securely. The decryptor then works in reverse, taking BOTH artifacts as input, reproducing the payload.

Comment: I am writing the ciphertext to a file.  I then can write the key to a text file, after writing this key to a text file I am unable to load it to the decryptor program and have it work like if it was in the same program.  The program crashes, possibly due to having a new box created?  It reads that the string must use binary encoding.  I am having the issue of passing the key and having it work with the other program.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a complete example that answers your question. A tip: Provide enough information so others can get to the same place you're stuck. Saying things like "it reads that..." is much less descriptive than simply pasting the entire error output, verbatim, into your question. Also, learn to break down a large problem into smaller manageable ones. It was unclear whether you had difficulty writing files to disk, understanding encryption, or (as it turns out) encoding strings.